# How to convert file to base64 UTF-8 little endian

Tags: c#, base64, endianness

Good day!

I convert binary file into char array:

```
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"file.wav");
char[] outArr = new char[(int)(Math.Ceiling((double)bytes.Length / 3) * 4)];
var result = Convert.ToBase64CharArray(bytes, 0, bytes.Length, outArr, 0,  Base64FormattingOptions.None);

string resStr = new string(outArr);
```

So, is it little endian?
And does it convert to UTF-8?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have any UTF-8 here - and UTF-8 doesn't have an endianness anyway, as its code unit size is just a single byte.

Your code would be simpler as:

```
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"file.wav");
string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```

If you then write the string to a file, *that* would have an encoding, which could easily be UTF-8 (and will be by default), but again there's no endianness to worry about.

Note that as base64 text is always in ASCII, each character within a base64 string will take up a single byte in UTF-8 anyway. Even if UTF-8 *did* have different representations for multi-byte values, it wouldn't be an issue here.

Comment: Yes,after that i write base64 to txt- File.WriteAllLines(..,coll);

Comment: @user2545071: Right - so *that's* where an encoding comes in, and it would have been useful to say that before :) If you don't specify an encoding, that will use UTF-8.

Answer (score 2):

- C# `char` represents a UTF-16 character element. So there is no UTF-8 here.
- Since .net is little endian, and since `char` is two bytes wide, then the `char` array, and the string, are both stored in little endian byte order.

If you want to convert your byte array to base64 and then encode as UTF-8 do it like this:

```
byte[] base64utf8 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Convert.ToBase64String(bytes));
```

If you wish to save the base64 text to a file, encoded as UTF-8, you could do that like so:

```
File.WriteAllText(filename, Convert.ToBase64String(bytes), Encoding.UTF8);
```

Since UTF-8 is a byte oriented encoding, endianness is not an issue.